# Profile Manager not sending email invitations

Tags: email, osx-server, ssl, profile-manager, volume-purchase-program

After installing a new copy of OSX Server I started the Profile Manager and wanted to add some users and enroll them for the VPP Managed Distribution (I am already registered for VPP).

In the VPP Managed Distribution section I hit "Resend invitation..." and a success message is displayed, but no invitation is received.

The possible causes:

- Missing SSL certificate
- Misconfigured e-mail in OSX server
- Misconfigured DNS

I tried different email addresses and checked spam, but none of it helped.

Why are my invitations not sent?

[image: Confirmation of invitation being sent]

Answer (score 1):

1. When you acquire VPP app licenses for free applications, are they appearing in your Apps tab in the Profile Manager [device manager interface] sidebar?
2. Have your devices successfully enrolled to Profile Manager, and can you deploy configuration payloads/profiles to them?

We ran into this when getting OS X Server and PM up and running, and then realized you can distribute apps and books without requiring the user to approve these VPP invitations.

Unless you're attempting to deploy internal/enterprise apps, you can deploy App Store/VPP apps to devices or device groups as long as they are enrolled to Profile Manager (supervised or not, they should deliver as long as your config profiles are).

EDIT: You should also make sure that you have an APNs account and that APNs is enabled in your OS X Server, with an updated token.

> If you‘re not getting Apple push notifications - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609
>
> Resolve issues with Profile Manager in macOS Server -  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201063